# Without making s3 bucket public how can we host website

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to host submit form  index.hmtl file in s3 bucket with out public access

```
             {
                "Version": "2008-10-17",
                "Id": "permissionTohttps",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "AddPerm",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:root"
                        },
                        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-2018/test/*",
                        "Condition": {
                            "Bool": {
                                "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Trying to host submit form  index.hmtl file in s3 bucket with out public access

Answer (score 2):

If you enable website hosting on an S3 bucket, it's going to be public.

It's not clear exactly how you want to restrict access to the web-form, but you could accomplish this by disabling website hosting on the bucket, then setting up an AWS CloudFront distribution that uses your S3 bucket as the origin (the source files for the distribution). You can then require signed URLs to access the CloudFront distribution (which would require you to have some other website that can issue signed URLs).  You could alternatively use WAF rules (Web ACLs) that only allow requests from an IP range that you desire.

Comment: We will not have any range of Ip'S.

Comment: Then your options are really limited, to hiding the S3 bucket behind a CloudFront distribution. Another idea would be to host the form in a Lambda function that is behind API Gateway, then you could restrict access to the API Gateway endpoint with Cognito, or a custom authorizer. If your company uses Active Directory and ADFS, Cognito integrates with that (and any OpenID Connect providers, etc)